# HTML5 - Free video player in html5

Tags: html, video, html5-video, video-player

I have videos locally in my web server and I want to embed it into a html document. I want to have a player to allow the user to stop the video, to control the sound, to continue seeing it. Do you know any video player free to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure a player is needed, seeing as you'd like HTML5, it's built in!

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>HTML5 BUILT IN Video Player</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <video controls>
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.webm">
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4">
      Your browser does not support HTML5 Video.
    </video>
  </body>
</html>
```

Use the video tag...

Comment: I used the tag `video`with a mp4 video and it doesn't work. Maybe wrong configurated.

Comment: Well, you have to make sure the file is on your webserver! Otherwise use the syntax for just one format: `<video src="video.mp4" controls></video>`